# entering and exiting the Pip mode is reseting the UI

Tags: android, react-native, picture-in-picture

How to implement a react native app with picture in picture mode, where in the UI does not reset on entering and exiting the PIP mode, I have successfully implemented the PIP mode using the React-Native modules but the blocker is that the whole app resets when I enter the pip mode and when I exit the PIP mode, found many solutions for it, but none of them worked

I tried all the solution in different stackoverflow